# Adding custom properties from AspNetUsers Table to /Manage/Index in .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm using .net mvc authentication and i've added a few different fields to the AspNetUsers table like First Name. When the user registers into the system including entering their first name it is inputted into that table and that works fine.

What I want to do is make a few of the fields (eg. firstname, lastname) from AspNetUsers editable in /Manage/Index. /Manage/Index uses the IndexViewModel which is below.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public bool HasPassword { get; set; }
    public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactor { get; set; }
    public bool BrowserRemembered { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(ManageMessageId? message)
{
    ViewBag.StatusMessage = message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? 
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var model = new IndexViewModel
    {
        HasPassword = HasPassword(),
        PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
        TwoFactor = await  UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
        Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
        BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId)
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

My questions are:

1. Should I just create my own ChangeDetails view and controller and change firstname, lastname, etc in there?
2. Manage/Index uses @model IndexViewModel - i'm not entirely sure how to access the AspNetUser table with that IndexViewModel - i suppose if userId is available i could just query the table with that id.
3. Can all this be done easily in Manage/Index and i'm making it harder than necessary.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've added the additional properties to the `ApplicationUser` class in `Models\IdentityModels.cs`, You can modify `IndexViewModel.cs` like so:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public bool HasPassword { get; set; }
    public IList<UserLoginInfo> Logins { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool TwoFactor { get; set; }
    public bool BrowserRemembered { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the `Index` action method of `ManageController.cs`, get the `ApplicationUser` reference for the current user using the `UserManager`:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var model = new IndexViewModel
{
    HasPassword = HasPassword(),
    PhoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(userId),
    TwoFactor = await UserManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(userId),
    Logins = await UserManager.GetLoginsAsync(userId),
    BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userId),
    CurrentUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId)
};
return View(model);
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks Jaime. Would you mind also just explaining why there is async/await when the properties of new IndexViewModel are being set?

Comment: The `FindByIdAsync` method executes on a separate thread from the main application, so it's using the `async / await` pattern to have it execute the task, but not lock up the current thread of execution. For a detailed explanation, see [Asynchronous Programming with async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jaime. One last question. When the user is done changing the details of some of the fields in AspNetUser eg. firstname, lastname from within Manage/Index when they post the changed data - i have to create a post method in the managecontroller that binds that data and puts it into the AspNetUser table is that correct?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't have to be a post method called index, you just need to specify which one with `@using Html.BeginForm`. See [Html.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Yeah that's great. Thanks.